# Microsoft flow queue Devops pipeline - parameter must be provided

Tags: azure-pipelines, power-automate

I'm trying to use Flow to queue a pipeline.

Pipeline has the following parameters:

```
# Pipeline Trigger
trigger:
- none

# Use parameters as input options
parameters:
- name: location
  displayName: Location?
  type: string
  values:
    - australiaeast
    - uksouth
    - eastus
    - westus2
    - southeastasia
```

And the flow:

[image]

I get an error:

```
Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.
Azure DevOps ActivityId: <id>
Details: {"ClassName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildRequestValidationFailedException","Message":"Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2146232832,"Source":null,"WatsonBuckets":null,"m_logException":false,"m_reportException":false,"m_errorCode":0,"m_logLevel":"warning","m_eventId":3000,"ValidationResults":[{"result":"error","message":"A value for the 'location' parameter must be provided."}
```

The JSON should be fine. Is it intended to work this way? To pass parameters to pipeline parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,

```
[
  {
    "location":"australiaeast"
  }
]
```

Gave me "Bad Gateway"

This did work:

```
{
"location":"uksouth"
}
```

The issue was some of the other parameters didn't have a default value set in the pipeline. After giving them default values I was able to pass in parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters should be in this format:

```
[
  {
    "location":"australiaeast"
  }
]
```

Comment: Although I would use `[{ "location": "australiaeast" }]` just to keep it clean since you only have one parameter.